# rest assured File not Found error

Tags: rest-assured

When i use authorization in headers for rest assured by bassing token variable giving "File Not Found" error. And if hardcode the token in headers then it's working successfully. Can anyone help me out what can be the issue. Below is my code,

```
public static void getIndentId() throws IOException {
if(indentId == null){
        Payloads pal = new Payloads();
        RestAssured.baseURI = CommonFunctions.getSitApiGatewayEndPoint();
        String sessionKey = GbPortalLogin.getSessionKey();
        String token = "Token "+sessionKey;
        System.out.println(token);
        Response res = given().
                header("Content-Type","application/json").
                header("Authorization",token).
                body(pal.createIndentPayload()).
                when().post(Resources.createNbIndent).
                then().extract().response();
        String s = res.asString();
        System.out.println(s);
        /*System.out.println(res.getBody().toString());
        JsonPath js = CommonFunctions.rawToJson(res);
        indentId = js.get("id").toString();*/
    }
```